# How to set background color of Metro Statusbar

Tags: c#, dotnetbar

I have used Dotnetbar to create a Metro Form application. In my form, there is a metro statusbar on bottom. How can I set its background color ? I tried to set BackColor in Properties but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the new color using `StyleManager`:

```
StyleManager.MetroColorGeneratorParameters = colorTheme;
```

Where `colorTheme` can be either a custom theme (the base color defines the color of the status bar):

```
var colorTheme = new MetroColorGeneratorParameters {
    BaseColor = Color.Red,
    CanvasColor = Color.White,
    ThemeName = "My theme"
};
```

or one of the predefined themes:

```
var predefinedThemes = MetroColorGeneratorParameters.GetAllPredefinedThemes();
```